# I cant install the Camera in Ionic v3

Tags: npm, ionic3, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

I'm building an Ionic App in which I want to use the cordova camera plugin, therefore I do type:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera
```

And then I do:

```
npm install --save @ionic-native/camera
```

Here I'm getting this warnings:

```
npm WARN @ionic-native/camera@5.0.0 requires a peer of @ionic-native/core@5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
```

After that when I include the camera plugin in the app.module and in the list of providers Im getting this message:

```
Error: Invalid provider for the NgModule 'AppModule' - only instances of Provider and Type are allowed, got: [StatusBar, SplashScreen, [object Object], ?[object Object]?]
at syntaxError (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:74769:34)
at http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:89925:40
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at CompileMetadataResolver._getProvidersMetadata (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:89893:19)
at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:89463:50)
at JitCompiler._loadModules (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:107787:87)
at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:107748:36)
at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:107664:37)
at CompilerImpl.compileModuleAsync (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:73605:49)
at PlatformRef.bootstrapModule (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:5747:25)
```

Comment: Im also getting this one :c
 Argument of type '{ declarations: (typeof HomePage | typeof MyApp)[]; imports: (ModuleWithProviders | typeof Browse...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NgModule'. Types of property 'providers' are incompatible. Type '(typeof SplashScreen | CameraOriginal | { provide: typeof ErrorHandler; useClass: typeof IonicErr...' is not assignable to type 'Provider[]'. Type 'typeof SplashScreen | CameraOriginal | { provide: typeof ErrorHandler; useClass: typeof IonicErro...' is not assignable to type 'Provider'. Type 'CameraOriginal' is not assignable to type 'Provider

Comment: even for me after ionic 4 release I am not able to install the plugins in Ionic 3

Answer (score 1):

Due to the release of Ionic 4, installing Ionic Native plugins for Ionic 3 requires appending `@4` when installing for Ionic 3. So to resolve this, uninstall the plugin with `npm uninstall --save @ionic-native/camera`, then reinstall with `npm uninstall --save @ionic-native/camera@4` and the issue will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the `ionic/core` dependency modules. So install them by the following command 
`npm i @ionic-native/core`

and try to install `camera`

`ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera`

`npm install --save @ionic-native/camera`

and before proceeding to other steps, please check them whether they add or in the `package.json` and `config.xml`

Comment: Hello!

After running
`npm i @ionic-native/core`

I'm still getting the following message:

npm WARN @ionic-native/camera@5.0.0 requires a peer of @ionic-native/core@5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

+ @ionic-native/core@4.3.2
updated 1 package and audited 6811 packages in 4.61s